# Is there a way to remove a previously outputed dataframe before displaying a updated version?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been creating a dataframe that stores the information about a portfolio of stocks. I created a function to refresh prices and want it to run automatically every minute, then output an updated version of the dataframe. With the current code, it just outputs the updated dataframe below the outdated dataframe. Is there a way to remove the outdated output before outputing the current updated dataframe. Sorry if this was confusing I am new to programming and any help would be much appreciated.

```
import time
  
while(True):
    refresh_prices()
    display(portfoliodf)
    time.sleep(60)
```

I looked at guides online and they all just showed solutions for when I am printing a statement, not displaying a dataframe.

Comment: try adding: ```clear_output(wait=True)``` after the refresh, also you're gonna need this: ```from IPython.display import clear_output```

Comment: You can use `os.system('cls')` to clear the screen (on windows).

Comment: terminal or jupyter notebook? windows or not? how about `import colorama`? or how about making a GUI instead? or use one of these newfangled data visualization libraries that do their "gui" in a browser, from your python process?